# Persistent redis handle in a lua script with nginx

Tags: nginx, lua, redis, openresty

I am using a lua script to push paramters into redis from a nginx http server
https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis

I do not want to make a new connection to redis server everytime. Can I persist the redis connection. Also is there an option to make this async

Comment: You can set keep alive connections between nginx and redis, check this https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis#set_keepalive

Comment: Ok if I set the keepalive how do I reuse the existing connection from the redis pool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [set_keepalive](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis#set_keepalive) specifying the connection pool size (2nd paramater), when you [connect](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis#connect), the lua-resty-redis library will automatically try to resolve a previous idle connection if any.
It also allows to specify a custom name for your pool. It is all decribed in ['redis#connect' method documentation](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis#connect):

> Before actually resolving the host name and connecting to the remote backend, this method will always look up the connection pool for matched idle connections created by previous calls of this method.
>
> An optional Lua table can be specified as the last argument to this method to specify various connect options:
>
> - pool
>
> Specifies a custom name for the connection pool being used. If omitted, then the connection pool name will be generated from the string template `<host>:<port>` or `<unix-socket-path>`.

As for the "async" requirement, the library is already [100% nonblocking](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis#description).